# Transform dictionary keys to uppercase

Tags: ansible

I have some ansible automation which deploys aws lambda functions. At some point I use below syntax:

```
env: "{{ l_common_env_vars | combine(l_per_env_vars) }}"
```

to create a dict with environment variables for a given function. The problem is that content of  `l_common_env_vars` and `l_per_env_vars` source dictionaries has lowercase keys, example:

```
redis_url: some_url
```

and as a result destination `env` dictionary has keys also in lowercase.
I would like to have all mentioned keys in uppercase:

```
REDIS_URL: some_url
```

I tried to use `{{ env | upper }}` but it changes case for both keys and their values which is not what I need:

```
REDIS_URL: SOME_URL
```

Is there any way to convert to uppercase only keys of `env` dictionary?

Thanks in advance for all help!

Best regards,
Rafal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea demonstrated below is to create tupples using `zip` of up-cased dict keys (using `map`) and values to reconstruct a dict using `items2dict`

The following playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Upcase dict keys
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    some_dict:
      redis_url: https://www.test.tld/
      some_other_key: other value

     some_dict_upper: >-
      {{
        some_dict.keys() | map('upper') 
        | zip(some_dict.values())
        | items2dict(key_name=0, value_name=1)
      }}

  tasks:
    - name: Show results
      debug:
        msg: "{{ some_dict_upper }}"
```

gives:

```
PLAY [Upcase dict keys] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Show results] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "REDIS_URL": "https://www.test.tld/",
        "SOME_OTHER_KEY": "other value"
    }
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: `items2dict requires a list, got <class 'zip'> instead`

Comment: `some_dict_upper: "{{ dict(some_dict.keys() | map('upper') | zip(some_dict.values())) }}"` seems to do the trick.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh  You are using ansible < 2.10. You need to explicitely cast of map/zip to a list before calling items2dict => `some_dict.keys() | map('upper') | zip(some_dict.values()) | list | items2dict(key_name=0, value_name=1)`